# Immediately undoing a vote still prevents you from voting later.

Tags: bug, status-bydesign

A couple of times now I've voted on something, decided to undo it to think some more or let other answers appear, and then gone back to vote much later.

Trying to vote at that point is refused, with a message that I voted on it 11 hours ago and it's locked in until an edit is made.  Checking the +/- counts, it's clear that my vote wasn't counted (e.g., it was '1' when I voted, and there's still only 1 positive vote).

Answer (score 1):

Yep, due to vote gaming, we only allow a 5 minute window for any voting changes.

If you want to change your vote, you'll need to edit the post first.

Comment: Just 'cause this is mildly ambiguous to me: I understand the limited time to change, but I figured that "neutral/haven't voted" was something you could still alter.  I.e. I went "Positive" then "neutral" (in about 15s), which worked.  Now I'm locked on "neutral".  Is that expected?

Comment: @exms It's to stop people from casting a downvote, waiting 4m59s, retracting it within the edit window and immediately recasting it, waiting another 4m59s, etc.